# react table Row component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that renders out the details of a list..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default RecordListDetail = ({details}) => {

  return (<tr>
         <td>{details.coreURL}</td>
         <td>{details.source}</td>
      </tr>
   )
 };
```

However this list changes and so I would like to programmatically generate this. With no success I have tried...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default RecordListDetail = ({details}) => {

  return (<tr>
  {details.map ((details, index) =>
  <td key={index}>
    {details}
  </td>
  )}
  </tr>
)};
```

It doesn't work though. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `details` is an object and not an array, you need to use something like [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of the keys. Now you can map the array of keys, and the values from details:

```
import React from 'react'; // no need to import Component

export default RecordListDetail = ({ details }) => (
    <tr>
        {Object.keys(details).map((key) =>
            <td key={ key }>
                { details[key] }
            </td>
        )}
    </tr>
);
```

Note: You can also use [Object#entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the keys, and the values, or [Object#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get just the values. However, Object#keys has more support.

**Working demo:**

```js
const RecordListDetail = ({ details }) => (
    <tr>
        {Object.keys(details).map((key) =>
            <td key={ key }>
                { details[key] }
            </td>
        )}
    </tr>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <RecordListDetail details={{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }} />
    </tbody>
  </table>,
  demo
);
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: One final question what is the best way to selectively not display certain <td>s as they are being mapped? Is this via a switch or a lodash _omit type affair?

Comment: You can use Array#filter to remove certain properties before mapping them by their key or value.

Comment: Great Thanks @OriDrori and as a "final final" point some of these <td>s will need formatting either as a hrefs or maybe with a modal etc. Presume this is a complex issue. Shall I open this in another question?

Comment: Welcome :) Open a new question and include: The original model/s, the expected result, and the current code relevant to the question. The relevant part is very important.

Comment: Question posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252150/react-programmatically-creating-table-tds