# React: Programmatically Creating table <td>s

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that renders out a `<tr>` and `<td>`s for a row in a table from this code:

```
import React from 'react';

export default RecordListDetail = ({ details }) => (

<tr>
  {delete details.owner}
  {delete details._id}

    {Object.keys(details).map((key) =>
        <td key={ key }>
            { details[key] }
        </td>
    )}
</tr>
);
```

This is my data passed in with props.

```
{
campaign: "Charles",
company_ID :"1"
coreURL :"http://test88.com",
Url2 :” http://test88.com/verylong/verylong/other/other/url",
Url3 : “http://test88.com/user",
updatedAt :"2017-11-06T20:44:14.027Z”,
createdAt :"2017-11-06T20:44:14.027Z",
medium :”twitter"
}
```

Some of these fields may not be present in each pass (hence the programmatic approach) however I do need to add specific formatting for each property if present.

This formatting will include:

- Using moment to format the dates,
- making the urls links (whilst also removing the http:// element in the display),
- truncate the very long urls and only have the full url showing up in a rollover modal

Many Thanks

Comment: Why the down vote? For a formatting typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do not delete keys from props, or change them in any other way. It will very likely cause issues.

Otherwise, something like this might work:

```
function buildTd(key, value) {
    let content;
    let width = "10%"; // default
    switch (key) {
        case "medium": 
            content = <b>{value}</b>; 
            break;
        case "coreURL": 
        case "Url2":
            content = <a href={value}>{shortenUrl(value)}</a>;
            width = "20%";
            break;
        // etc, leave out those you don't want like owner or _id
    }

    return content && <td key={key} width={width}>{content}</td>;
}

export default RecordListDetail = ({ details }) => (
    <tr>
        { Object.keys(details).map(key => buildTd(key, details[key])) }
    </tr>
);
```

Comment: It does seem to break when you don't lead the content with an HTML tag e.g. <B> or <a... and just have some javascript e.g. content = {javascript in here}

Comment: well, what exactly do you mean by break and what is the content you'd like to use? in the "example" you give, I'd expect to see no curly braces, e.g. `content = someFunction()` or `content = value`..

Comment: Thanks I think I have it. case "createdAt":
          content = moment(value).format('DD MMM YY');
          break;

Comment: what is the best way to programmatically add a pre-defined width=??% to each <td> column? Thanks

Comment: not sure what the problem is? Just add it to <td>, as in `<td key={key} width="??%">`?